# Mac OSX? Linux? X? Gnome? KDE? Why is osx considered linux and why is it not considered linux?

Tags: linux, macos

I'm not sure how to ask this question so here goes...

Software sometimes says available on all "*nix" and that means osx and linux, or it may say available on linux and not mac or vice versa. So when I ask what makes them similar/different, I guess I'm asking what are these operating systems made up of and what allows them to be different and similar at the same time. I read somewhere that mac osx is based on bsd and something about debian and kernels and window managers and..... I'm just very confused.

Comment: MacOSX is not linux, it is a unix variant.  There is a difference.  Also SO is normally for programming questions.

Comment: Linux and Mac-OS are both UNIX-like operating systems that are NOT strictly speaking UNIX, although OS X has a legitimate claim to "being a Unix".  Saying that Mac OS is Linux is like saying that Bananas and Oranges are apples.  No. Bananas, Oranges, and Apples, are all fruit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X is not Linux. OS X is UNIX.

The lower level system APIs are very similar (identical in many cases) - C, 'nix, POSIX, and so on. A program using these interfaces can be ported easily to the other (consider the of libraries which are compatible on both and require little to no platform specific features).

There are of course differences. The OS X kernel is a microkernel (Darwin), while Linux is monolithic. Divergence beyond core user-land layers happens pretty quickly, particularly wrt the user interfaces.

Comment: I would have said it's a Unix-derivative, called Darwin, using a Mach microkernel.

Comment: @WarrenP i was expanding when you wrote that :)

Answer (score 2):

Linux is not the general variant, Unix is.  Linux is a form of Unix, as are the BSD derivatives (including OS X), Solaris, AIX, and a number of others.

What makes a Unix, officially, is compliance with (and, preferably, certification of) the Open Group's Unix specification.  Most Unixes also provide functionality (and standard functions) beyond that specification, however, and it's in that area that you most often run into compatibility questions, although questions of device driver availability and other things not directly related to OS interfaces come in to it as well.